# Problems with Twitter+OAuth+iPhone. Kids are Crying

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth

This case is really strange, i've spent 2 whole days to get Twitter Oauth working with the iPhone and i failed over and over again. Its strange since most of the people don't seem to have the same problem as me.

First of all, the Consumer Key and Consumer Secret is okay, i tried with 2 OAuth apps (Twitter) with every possible configuration and got nothing, i even tried with a completely funcional app and the result was the same. **So the Twitter app is okay, the problem doesnt lie there.**

I've tried **Bengottlieb's** solution: http://github.com/bengottlieb/Twitter-OAuth-iPhone provided my Consumer Key and Secret and all i've got from Twitter is a "Sorry, the page doesn't exist".

I tried with "ShareKit" which is intended to be a n00b's proof drop in component, you just need to provide your Consumer key and Consumer Secret and i receive the message: "Request Error: There was a problem requesting authorization from Twitter".

I've tried including only OAuthConsumer and implementing code as tutorials say and i receive again the "Sorry, the page doesn't exist" page.

**I'm using XCode 3.2.3 with the SDK 4.0** and i will download the 3.2.4 as another desperate solution.

Any help will be appreciated and maybe you achieve to make kids stop crying :'(

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you said your consumer key / secret pair are correct, but unless you started messing around in ShareKit's code, that's basically the only thing that could be wrong. Are you absolutely, 100% sure you're using the consumer key and secret provided to you by Twitter when you registered the application?

Comment: I'm sure they were right but since you took your time to help i am trying once more and. 1.- I am resetting the Consumer key / secret and copied them to TextEdit(notepad). 2. Then i download the ShareKit 0.2.1 and open the example project. 3. i provide the obtained Consumer key/secret pair, modifying the parameters SHKTwitterConsumerKey,SHKTwitterSecret and SHKTwitterCallbackUrl matches the "callback URL" specified in the apps contiguration. 4. Testing and.... failed 5.- Checking provided parameters and they are okay, the app is configured to accept Login from Twitter. Any other suggestion? :(

Comment: Change `SHKDebugShowLogs` (in `SHKConfig.h`) to 1, and see what the request response body is (should print in the console). That should give a bit more information as to what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Gordon!

Answer (score 11):

**Thanks Gordon**, your advice took me to the solution. I was receiving from Twitter the message "Failed to validate oauth signature and token". I googled it and found that i needed to change the Time zone.

If someone has the same problem on your Mac do this:

-Click on the clock and then "Date & Time preferences"
-**Check** "Set date and time automatically with: Apple Americas/U.S. (time.apple.com)"

That's all, the problem was with the timestamp which had been generated with an incorrect hour.

2 days wasted for such stupid thingy XD

Comment: That's ridiculous. Glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: I want to up vote you +1000 for finding out the solution. I am also facing the same problem but unable to finding out the solution. then i google it and find your answer. and i solved my problem.

Comment: Leopoldo, you rock! Twitter - I hate you!

Answer (score 1):

Same problem occurred in device. It was because of the wrong time in device. If the device time is set in the past(like the real time is 10:00, but time is set as 9:30 in device), then also this problem will arise.

So, check your time setting in device, if this problem arises.